# how to divide an image to blocks of 8x8 image and access each

Tags: r, bigdata

I have an image as below. It is 256*256 pixels. Let's assume that it's bottom left corner is at 0,0. From that image, I want to create multiple images as follows and save them in the working folder. Each image will have size of 8*8 pixels. Each image will be saved by its bottom left-hand coordinates.

example raster image

```
library(raster)
dem <- raster(nrow=256, ncol=256, vals=1:(256*256))
```

I have used following code to split the image into 8*8 blocks

```
agg      <- aggregate(raster(dem),fact=c(8,8))
agg_poly <- rasterToPolygons(agg)
r_list <- list()
for(i in 1:ncell(agg)){
    r_list[[i]] <- crop(dem, agg_poly[i,])
}
```

How can it be done in R without using raster scan library?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Could you please outline what you have tried?

Comment: I have loaded an image in memory and used raster library to split it in 8*8 pixel blocks.

Comment: polarise i have edited my question

Comment: So your question is how to do this without using the `raster` package?

Comment: yes, need to do without raster package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something along these lines

```
d <- as.matrix(dem)
ii <- seq(1, nrow(dem), 8)
jj <- seq(1, ncol(dem), 8)
r <- list()
q <- 1
for (i in ii) {
    for (j in jj) {
        r[[q]] <- d[i:(i+7), j:(j+7)]
        q <- q + 1
    }
}
```

*With* the raster package you could do (to keep RasterLayer objects):

```
d <- dem
ii <- seq(1, nrow(dem), 8)
jj <- seq(1, ncol(dem), 8)
r <- list()
q <- 1
for (i in ii) {
    for (j in jj) {
        r[[q]] <- d[i:(i+7), j:(j+7), drop=FALSE]
        q <- q + 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, do you know how can  "r" be binded to obtain matrix of 1024*64 from image size of 256*256 (considering 8*8 block at a time) thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it

```
data = readImage("reSizedDogCatLatest.jpg")
grayimage<-channel(data,"gray")

CutBySize <- function(m, block.size, nb = ceiling(m / block.size)) {
  int <- m / nb
  upper <- round(1:nb * int)
  lower <- c(1, upper[-nb] + 1)
  size <- c(upper[1], diff(upper))
  df = data.frame()
  df = cbind(lower, upper, size)
  return(df)
}
mf = data.frame()
mf = CutBySize(nrow(grayimage), nb = 32)
numextract <- function(string){
  str_extract(string, "\\-*\\d+\\.*\\d*")
}
final = data.frame()
libraray(stringr)
for (i in 1:nrow(mf))
{
  lower = numextract(mf[i,][1])
  upper = numextract(mf[i,][2])
  for(j in 1:nrow(mf))
  {
    lowerj = numextract(mf[j,][1])
    upperj = numextract(mf[j,][2])
    final = rbind(final,grayimage[lower:upper, lowerj:upperj])
  }
}
```